# ScriptableObject asset changes with its instance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a ScriptableObject Item and created a preset for it:

```
public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
    public enum ItemType
    {
        Key,
        Consumable
    }
    public new string name;
    public ItemType itemType;
    public string description;
    public int amount = 1;
    public bool isStackable = false;
}
```

Matches.asset:

[image: Matches.asset]

Using script I add this item asset to inventory:

```
SC_FPSController.inventory.AddItem(item);
```

```
public void AddItem(Item item)
    {
        if (!item.isStackable || itemList.Count == 0)
        {
            itemList.Add(item);

        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Item invItem in itemList)
            {
                if (invItem.name == item.name)
                {
                    invItem.amount += item.amount;
                }
                else
                {
                    itemList.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I remove items amount, it changes not only itemList item, but asset as well.

```
public void RemoveItem(Item item)
    {
        Item searchedItem = itemList.Find(i => i.name == item.name);
        searchedItem.amount -= 1;
        if (searchedItem.amount == 0)
        {
            itemList.Remove(searchedItem);
        }
    }
```

So when I invoke RemoveItem function, asset becomes like this:
[image]

How to fix this and what is wrong? Maybe it takes item asset as pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the changes you want in run-time, and to make sure they do not affect the original Asset call Instantiate, and use the returned value (this will make a copy from the original one).

```
var itemInstance = GameObject.Instantiate(asset);
itemInstance.DoWhatever();
```

Comment: To avoid the confusion it is simply `Object.Instantiate(...)` ;)